# How to remove KAPT, KSP generated files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using version ***Android Studio Flamingo***

[image]

After using `KAPT` and `KSP`, there are new build folders generated and Android Studio is showing those folders. How can I hide those folder when selecting Android option, from Android Studio???

[image]